# purpose of の in 人の嫌がることをするな

Tags: particle-の

In this phrase 人の嫌がることをするな why is の used? Is it acting as a noun modifier?

嫌がる is the  garu form of iya as far as I understand, so it would be a verb right? can a verb be treated as a noun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 嫌がる is an attributive form of a verb 嫌がる. So 嫌がること is a noun phrase.　人の嫌がること is translated as "something that a person(or someone) doesn't want to do". This の act as が like 人が嫌がること.